# Can't create KSQL UDF jar

Tags: apache-kafka, confluent-platform, ksqldb

I implemented a UDF (User-Defined-Function) for KSQL and configured the Maven pom.xml file according to https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/udf.html

When I try to create the jar file with `mvn clean package` I run into the following error:

```
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal on project CustomUDF: Could not resolve dependencies for project XXXX:CustomUDF:jar:1.0-SNAPSHOT: Failure to find kafka-avro-confluent:kafka-avro-confluent:jar:0.1.0 in http://packages.confluent.io/maven/ was cached in the local repository, resolution will not be reattempted until the update interval of confluent has elapsed or updates are forced -> [Help 1]
```

I found a related issue in the schema registry GitHub FAQ:
https://github.com/confluentinc/schema-registry/wiki/FAQ#when-i-try-to-compile-i-get-an-error-about-a-missing-snapshot-dependency

Is this the proper way to fix my error? I tried to follow the instructions to build the dependencies but the `./gradlew installAll` lead only to more errors (which I could share if that's the correct approach to fix my error).

What does "Alternatively, use a release tag (e.g. v3.2.0) as the basis of a new development branch." mean in detail? Would this be an appropriate alternative?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update: I was able to create the jar file by creating it directly with IntelliJ instead of shell commands:

I opened the Maven window and chose `My Project name -> Lifecycle -> install -> Run Maven Build` which created the jar in the target subfolder of my IntelliJ project folder.

Afterwards I followed the normal KSQL UDF deployment steps (https://docs.confluent.io/current/ksql/docs/developer-guide/udf.html#deploying) and everything worked fine.